# Criar Loop de página 3 vezes

Tags: php

O usuário entrará no sistema, fará um outro cadastro em uma página não relacionada a essa pergunta e chegará nessa página *cadastro_diretor.php*. Na página em questão, ele irá cadastrar 3 diretores diferentes, sendo que por ter somente 1 formulário, ele deve ir e voltar 3 vezes na mesma página, como fazer isso?

Comment: So não entendi o pq do while, quando vc chama o `header()` o script acaba não vai executar mais nenhuma linha abaixo.

Comment: Na pratica ele vai inserir 3 cadastros, certo? porque não faz um form que a pessoa possa cadastrar `N` diretores ao invés de ficar redirecionando.

Comment: Eu não entendi o porque de chamar o header 3 vezes, mas respondi do Laço de repetição.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Com uma estrutura de repetição você não conseguirá fazer isso, o certo seria:

**cadastro_diretor.php**

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['cadastro_cont'])
    $_SESSION['cadastro_cont'] = 1;

// restante da ação da página
```

**insert_diretor.php**

```
// ação da página
<?php
//no fim, quando terminar de cadastrar:

if($_SESSION['cadastro_cont'] >= 3)
    header('Location: pagina_seguinte.php');

$_SESSION['cadastro_cont'] += 1;
header('Location: cadastro_diretor.php');
```

Na primeira vez que acesso a página de cadastro uma variável de sessão é criada para contar qual o cadastro atual. Na página de insert, depois da ação inserir, verifico se o cadastro atual representado por essa variável é 3 se for eu encaminho para a próxima tela, se não eu atribuo mais um ao contador e chamo a página de cadastro novamente.

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que você possui a relação entre as tabelas **empresa** e **diretor**, de forma a armazenar o `id` da empresa no cadastro do diretor, algo como:

```
create table empresas 
(
  id int,
  name varchar(255)
);

create table diretores (
  id int,
  name varchar(255),
  empresa int
);
```

Em um arquivo, possivelmente chamado `insert_empresa.php`, é efetuado o cadastro da empresa. Para fins de exemplo:

```
insert into empresas (id, name) values (1, "empresa_1");
```

Este `insert` gera um `id`, relacionado ao registro da empresa, que é passado ao arquivo `cadastro_diretor.php`, onde é exibido o formulário. No arquivo `insere_diretor.php`, você cria o registro do diretor, armazenando no campo **empresa** o `id` da empresa relacionada.

```
insert into diretores (id, name, empresa) values (1, "diretor_1", 1);
```

Para saber se ainda não foram cadastrados os três diretores, basta contar o número de registros no banco:

```
select count(*) from diretores where empresa = 1;
```

Onde `empresa = 1` refere-se ao `id` da empresa em questão. Essa consulta retorna um valor inteiro e se for inferior a 3, redirecione o usuário novamente a página do formulário.

Veja no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Q5wNvt) e no [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/acwoss/f25b44083ba4b9786130e79185bdb8a0).

Answer (score 1):

Seria melhor colocar um botão no formulário da página cadastro_diretor.php, para que o usuário adicionasse novos cadastros. Aí você coloca um controle pra permitir que o usuário cadastre até 3 pessoas ou exatamente 3 pessoas.

Comment: Consegue detalhar melhor sua resposta? Se possível com exemplos que possam ser reproduzidos. Fazendo isso aumentará a qualidade do conteúdo na comunidade.